# h2o Steam Prediction Servlet not accepting character values from python script

Tags: h2o

I am using Steam to attempt to build a prediction service using a python preprocessing script. When python passes the cleaned data to the prediction service in the

```
variable:value var2:value2 var3:value3
```

format (as seen in the [Spam Detection Example](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/tree/master/prediction-service-builder/examples/spam-detection-python)) I get a

```
ERROR PredictPythonServlet - Failed to parse
```

error from the service. When I look at the [PredictPythonServlet.java](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/src/PredictPythonServlet.java) file it seems to only use the `strMapToRowData` function which assumes every value in the input string is a number:

```
for (String p : pairs) {
    String[] a = p.split(":");
    String term = a[0];
    double value = Float.parseFloat(a[1]);
    row.put(term, value);
  }
```

Are character values not allowed to be sent in this format? If so is there a way to get the `PredictPythonServlet` file to use the `csvToRowData` function that is defined but never used? I'd like to not have to use One-Hot encoding for my models so being able to pass the actual character string representation would be ideal.

Additionally, I passed the numeric representation found in the model pojo file for the categorical variables and received the error:

```
hex.genmodel.easy.exception.PredictUnknownTypeException: Unexpected object type java.lang.Double for categorical column home_team
```

So it looks like the service expects a character string but I can't figure out how to pass it along to the actual model. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prediction service is using EasyPredictModelWrapper and it can only use what the underlying model uses. Here it's not clear what model you use, but most use numerical float values. In the for loop code snippet you can see that the number has to be float.

Comment: I'm using a GBM model and using the `Enum` categorical handling so the model knows to accept strings for those variables, not numeric values.

Comment: Hi Matt, I modified the code to fall back to using the string if it can't parse it as a float. The code has been pushed so this should work for you now.

Comment: I've submitted a PR (https://github.com/h2oai/steam/pull/375) to add this change to the strMapToRowData function as well. The GBM model I am using seems to default to strMapToRowData not the sparseToRowData function